# Skinning 'Tech Crush' Game

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I'm trying to skin this Match-3 style game however the image source is being written by the javascript and its kind of throwing me for a loop.

Here is a link to it: http://codepen.io/drewlandon/pen/RNEqwJ

```
var logoSource = "data:image/png;base64,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 etc etc ";
```

Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: That's a data URI, more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Base64-encoded image, where the image data is actually encoded as this really long string.

If you copy and paste the full string into your browser location bar, you should be able to see the sprite image they used, its dimensions are 700px W x 70px H.

You can make a new skin if you create an image with those same dimensions, which consists of 10 icons side by side, each 70 x 70 pixels.

Once you have the image file as a PNG, you should be able to use a site [like this one](http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/image-to-base64/) or you can use [GIMP](http://gimp.org) to [generate a Base64 string](http://dev-maziarz.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/gimp-how-to-export-image-to-base64.html).

Then just fork the CodePen, replace their base64 string with yours, and voila! New skin.